# Any empirical length limits or caveats about MP4's of 7400 seconds?

Tags: video, mp4

I was investigating a curious issue I have with the playback of certain MP4 files on my BluRay player; in particular, it seemed files over two hours simply would not play (player locked up).

As I researched this issue and found precious little precedent, I *did* find some interesting information regarding certain "Smart TV" devices (at least one made by Samsung) that would not play back an MP4 beyond *exactly* the 2:03:19 mark, which translates to 7,399 seconds. Although I had not proven that was the specific problem I was experiencing with my player, I knew the 2-hour boundary was conspicuous.

Does anyone know of any strange limitation or characteristic of MP4 files that would tie to this odd seconds limit? The 7,399 limit conspicuously sounds like an offset range cap from 0-7399, and the programmer in me started suspecting bit  packing limits, but nothing interesting arose with this particular number.

I thought perhaps others who might be more familiar with encoding/format histories might notice that number as having some magic relevance at some point.

Comment: Seems to be a TV issue, not a mp4 issue, better to stream it from a PC to the TV.

Comment: I suspect it is a TV issue, but was hoping perhaps this was an arcane limit inherited from early days of the spec that might have been errantly persisted in some later codecs. Worth a shot.